# make: Nothing to be done for `all' on Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to learn OpenCV following [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html#linux-eclipse-usage). But I cannot build the project.

When I try to build all I get this error:

```
22:49:54 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project OpenCVLearning ****
make all 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

22:49:55 Build Finished (took 135ms)
```

When I try to run I get this message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
```

Here is the content of the Make file:

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include src/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: OpenCVLearning

# Tool invocations
OpenCVLearning: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
    g++ -L/usr/local/lib -o "OpenCVLearning" $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
    -$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C++_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS) OpenCVLearning
    -@echo ' '

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets
```

Source code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat image;
  image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

  if( argc != 2 || !image.data )
    {
      printf( "No image data \n" );
      return -1;
    }

  namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Display Image", image );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Why is it happening? How could I solve this?

Comment: I guess you get better help if you ask the developers. Or maybe [here](http://answers.opencv.org/questions/)

Comment: The `Incremental Build` is not a build error. It means no changed, no build.

Comment: How do you run it? Please paste your command to run. I think there are an error in your `argc` in main. You should run it by `./DisplayImage <your image path and name>`, see [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html#running-the-executable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a problem

> make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

it just means, that everything is already built and you're ready to go and test your executable.

The second one

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'  
  what():  basic_string::_S_construct null not valid
```

is a runtime error.

It says, that somewhere you or OpenCV pass a `NULL` pointer to a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) constructor, which is not allowed.

The only place, where this could happen in your code, might be

```
image = imread( argv[1], 1 );
```

when you call the executable without parameters. In this case `argc` is one and `argv[1]` is `NULL`.

Comment: You are right. I was waiting for something like this image from the tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/_images/a12.png. The run error was a stupid mistake. I forgot to pass the image parameter because I was running using F11 shortcut on Eclipse.